# Configure unattended-upgrades to run only at a certain time of the day?

Tags: unattended-upgrades, schedule

I have some kind of internet that I don't really recommend to anyone, but there -- it's a limiter traffic (4G from a mobile carrier).
Fortunately, in a way, the night traffic is free, so I am looking for a way for my computers to automatically download and install updates. I think unattended-upgrades should be the way, however I'm not 100% sure if it supports this.

So, would there be a way to make it run only at 2 AM, for example?
Or, if not, is there an alternative?

Thank you!

Comment: See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticSecurityUpdates

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unattended-Upgrades is run by the script `apt-compat` (Ubuntu 14.04 or older: `apt`) in `/etc/cron.daily`.

So you could probably just edit your `/etc/crontab` to run `cron.daily` at a different time of the day or move it to a custom cronjob.

The script contains functions to sleep a short "random" amount of time (0-30mins) before executing `/usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily`, which you could edit out if you like.