# Run Ubuntu Security Updates every Sunday at 00:00 am

Tags: 14.04, server, security

I want apply security and updates patches on ubuntu servers every Sunday at 00:00 am.

Is there a way to make this every Sunday at 00:00 am ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Configure unattended-upgrades to run only at a certain time of the day?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/947629/configure-unattended-upgrades-to-run-only-at-a-certain-time-of-the-day)

Comment: Also related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/9/how-do-i-enable-automatic-updates/204

Comment: Above mentioned links do not make sense to me, Could please share me some steps.

Comment: Why are you running Ubuntu servers if you can't make sense of something as simple as `cron`?